# Can I copy video directly to the iPhone without iTunes?

Tags: iphone

If you connect your iPhone to your PC it shows up as a drive and you can browse your images in the DCIM\100Apple folder.

Is there any way to copy video to the phone without using iTunes?

Comment: Are you willing to jailbreak?

Comment: Good point. Hrm. I guess if that's the only way... I have no idea why I haven't jailbroken yet. Seems like a no brainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a genre of iPhone app that allows you to move files to and from the iPhone/Touch. I happen use one called '**Air Sharing**' which allows viewing of videos and other doc types within it.

They connect very easily assuming you have access to a Computer using Wi-Fi

Answer (score 1):

Jailbreaking might be the best solution.
There are some other tricky ways that don't require a jailbreak however.

If you have a [DropBox](http://www.getdropbox.com) account, you can download the FREE iPhone App. Drop some movies in your box, and you'll have access to them without iTunes.